# google api photos and oziogallery plugin in joomla

Tags: authentication, configuration, joomla, photo, google-photos-api

On my websites i use the plugin oziogallery to display the contents of albums that are stored on google photos.
It uses the api google photos with oauth2 authentication and credentials to do this.
on the sites which url are of the type http://www.monsite.fr it doesn't work, i have error messages in users and administrator spaces.
i have duplicated one of this sites which url is now :https://www.monsite1.fr, and on this last one it works; i can visualize the content of the albums.
Perhaps the api google photos and its uthentiction doesn't work with websites which url is of type "http"?
Can somebody confirm we that? or can you indicate me how i had to configure the api in order that it works with "http" websites?
Thank you in advance for your answers.
jeanluc.ferré

i duplicated wy http://www.monsite.fr website which becomes https://www.monsite1.fr and it works for displaying the content of albums stored in google photo.
i should want to know how to configure the google api photo and authentication in order that it works for websites which url re of the type :http://www.monsite.fr.
Thank you.